# Flutter doctor not giving feedback

Tags: flutter

I am trying to run flutter doctor but it returns nothing. Below is a screenshot:[screenshot of flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w4YM.png)

Comment: Can you add more detail, like when are you start getting this issue? Is this the first time you are installing it? etc.

Comment: I updated it recently.